# drop down list at header navbar not working well with page tabs

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i wrote code that shows tabs on page it works fine but the problem is that when i press some tabs , i cant see the drop down list for the main navbar at layout page it looks looks like idle then  i should press tab twice to appear that so how can i solve this

i appreciate your assistance

thanks

this is code for tabs

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" class="nav_link" data_id="1" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" class="nav_link" data_id="2" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" class="nav_link" data_id="3" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
            </ul>




            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">


                    <div id="ProductsDiv1">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">

                    <div id="ProductsDiv2">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">

                    <div id="ProductsDiv3">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

this is jquery

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        $(".nav_link").click(function () {
            //Custom attribute data_id is used to store the ID
            //Get the ID
            var id = $(this).attr("data_id");
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("View_All_SupportTickets_tab1", "etraining")',
                type: "get",
                dataType: "html",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify({ id: id }), //add parameter
                success: function (data) {
                    //success
                    $('#ProductsDiv'+id).html(data); //populate the tab content.
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        });
    });

    </script>
```

this is action controller

```
 public PartialViewResult View_All_SupportTickets_tab1()


    {

        var query = (from st in Db.Support_Teckets
                     join pr in Db.Technical_problem on st.Technical_problem_Id equals pr.Technical_problem_Id
                     where st.Status==null || st.Status==""
                     join x in

                     from rp in Db.Ticket_Reply.GroupBy(m =>
       m.Support_Tecket_Id).Select(m => m.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault())
                     join tr in Db.trainers on rp.trainer_id equals tr.trainer_id
                     select new { rp, tr }


       on st.Support_Tecket_Id equals x.rp.Support_Tecket_Id into g

                     from gx in g.DefaultIfEmpty()



                     select new SupportTicketsDetails
                     {
                         Support_Tecket_Id = st.Support_Tecket_Id,
                         Created_Date = st.Created_Date,
                         //Created_Time = st.Created_Time,
                         Order_by = Db.trainers.Where(b => b.trainer_id == st.trainer_id).FirstOrDefault().trainer_name,

                         Technical_problem_name = pr.Technical_problem_name,
                         Created_details = st.Created_details,
                         Location = st.Location,

                         Technician = Db.trainers.Where(b => b.trainer_id == st.Current_Technician_Id).FirstOrDefault().trainer_name,
                         Status = string.IsNullOrEmpty(gx.rp.Status) ? "بلاغ جديد" : gx.rp.Status,

                         //Closing_Date = st.Closing_Date ,

                         Last_replier = Db.trainers.FirstOrDefault(a => a.trainer_id == gx.rp.trainer_id).trainer_name.ToString(),


                         Last_reply_Date = gx.rp.Date,

                         //Last_reply_Time = gx.rp.Time,


                         //points = st.points



                     }).ToList().OrderByDescending(a => a.Created_Date);




        return PartialView("View_All_SupportTickets_tab1" ,query);



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two problems. The first problem is that you need to add the `id` as a parameter in View_All_SupportTickets_tab1() so you will use the `id` to filter your data. Second, you don't need to use `JSON.stringify` because, in this case, will not prepare you're sending data correctly and you need to use just `data: { id: id }`

Controller

```
public PartialViewResult View_All_SupportTickets_tab1(int id)
```

Javascript

```
data: { id: id }, //add parameter
```

Comment: thanks for your reply i've resolved the problem , because i have forgotten to set null value for tab view page :)  thanks again i appreciate your assistance